# $p$ continuous map with property of continuity of the composite, show that $p$ is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X, Y, Z$ be topological spaces and $p:X\rightarrow Y$ surjective
>   and continuous with the property: A function $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ is
>   continuous if and only if $g\circ p:X\rightarrow Z$ is continuous. Show $p$ is a quotient map

So i want to show that given an open subset $U\subseteq Y$ then $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, and given $p^{-1}(U)$ open in $X$, then $U$ is open in $Y$.

I'd say the that given open $U\subseteq Y$ then $p^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ is open, follows from the fact that $p$ is continuous, however, i'm having trouble with showing that given $p^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$, then $U\subseteq Y$ is open.

Comment: The problem statement seems wrong.  Why f and g?  Shouldn't there be a quantification for f,g, like for all f,g?

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, I wrote $f$ by a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $p:X \to Y$ obeys the property that

> for all functions $g: Y \to Z$, $g$ is continuous iff $g \circ p$ is continuous.

Then suppose that $U$ is a subset of $Y$ that satisfies $p^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$. Then define $Z = \{0,1\}$ with the topology $\{\{0\}, \emptyset, Z\}$ (the Sierpinski space) and define $g: Y \to Z$ by $g(y) = 0$ if $y \in U$, $g(y) = 1$ otherwise. Then $(g \circ p)^{-1}[\{0\}] = p^{-1}[g^{-1}[\{0\}]] = p^{-1}[U]$ is open, and as this $\{0\}$ the only non-trivial open set of $Z$, $g \circ p$ is continuous (the inverse image of $Z$ is just $X$, and of $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$ again, so these never have to be checked), and by the property of $p$ we know that $g$ is continuous, so $g^{-1}[\{0\}] = U$ is open in $Y$, as required.

On the other hand, if $U$ is open in $Y$ then the same function $g$ is continuous and so $g \circ p$ is continuous, which implies that $g^{-1}[U]= (g \circ p)^{-1}[\{0\}]$ is open in $X$. So $U$ open in $Y$ iff $p^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$. This means by definition that $p$ is quotient.

The last direction indeed follows directly if you assume $p$ is continuous. I wanted to show that the continuity of $p$ even follows from the “composition property”.